# Simpler way to add or update deeply nested model instance

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm working with a Postgres DB using Node/Sequelize. The database has 3 relevant models, Store, Product, and Offer. The store can have many Products, but Product belongs to one Store. Products can have many Offers, while Offers belong to one Product. To make it more complex, both Product and Offer have a surrogate Id of sorts to make it easier for human users to relate them to real-world products as opposed to noting the autogenerated IDs. So all Products will need to be looked up by 'sku', and all offers by 'offer_id' and Offers are added to a Product via their sku, not id.

```
const Product = sequelize.define(
  "product",
  {
    id: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      autoIncrement: true,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    sku: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    }
  },
  {
    indexes: [{ fields: ["sku", "storeId"], unique: true }]
  }
);

const Offer = sequelize.define(
  "offer",
  {
    id: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      autoIncrement: true,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    offer_id: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
      },
    product_sku: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
      }
  }
  ,
  {
    indexes: [{ fields: ["offer_id", "productId"], unique: true }]
  }
);
```

Given an array of offers, I need to update the offer if exists or create it if it doesn't exist yet.

```
function addOffer(newOffer, storeId) {
  //Find a product to add the offer to
  return Product.findOne({
    where: { sku: newOffer.product_sku, storeId: storeId }
  }).then(function(product) {
    if (product) {
      // Product found, check if offer exists
     return Offer
        .findOne({ where: { offer_id: newOffer.offer_id, productId: product.id } })
        .then(function(offer) {
          if (offer) {
            // update offer
            return offer.update({...newOffer });
          } else {
            // insert new offer
            return Offer.create({...newOffer,productId: product.id });
          }
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
    } else {    
      // Product not found
      return false;
    }
  });
}
exports.add_offers = async function(req, res) {
  const storeId = req.body.storeId;
  const offers = [
      {
        "offer_id": "122",
        "product_sku": "5722719"
      },
      {
        "offer_id": "123",
        "product_sku": "5722719"
      },
      {
        "offer_id": "124",
        "product_sku": "5822625"
      }
  ];

  for (const offer of accepted) {
    addOffer(offer, storeId)
      .then(function(result) {
        //res.status(200).send({ success: true });
      })
      .catch(err => {
       //handle error
      });
  }
}
```

The main problem I'm trying to fix is my addProduct() function. Since I have to first look up the item by sku+storeId to find the productID. Then check if the offer exists already with offer_id+productId. By the time I finally call update or create offer I'm on 3 network calls per offer. If my offer array is of any significant size then it will be incredibly inefficient.

Is there a simpler way?

Comment: I had encountered similar problems running complex business logic's code, only viable solution I came up with was moving part of the heavier business logic to database server side, if possible, aggregating tasks and passing data to functions which in turn perform all the necessary logic at once in just one call. Like for example, we had to recalculate FIFO price for 100k product sales years worth data, which took more than a hour to complete. When we moved calculations and updates to postgres functions, it then took less than a minute or two to calculate and update data.

Comment: I know its too late, but if you are still wanting to improve the query. 

Sequelize gives the option to use relations and eager loading.

There are three steps in your code. Product Search, Offer Search, Offer Create or update.

My advice - 
1) Find product and use eager loading in it to load its one offer with same offer id and the same product. Sequelize provides the option to filter related data.
2) Check if a relation exists if not insert otherwise update it.
Use the following link to see how easy Sequelize does the job - https://pastebin.com/LvQVFDru